# Javascript/Node Date specification

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, documentation

the official documentation for JS i know is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference 

 But i am curious if this also is the right place to look for when talking about NodeJS.
Here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date is the documentation about the `Date`

> Constructor:
>   new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);

and also

> `year`
>   Integer value representing the year. Values from 0 to 99 map to the years 1900 to 1999; all other values are the actual year. See the example below.
>   `monthIndex` Integer value representing the month, **beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December**.

If i execute the following code in Chrome i get a different result than in node JS CLI:

```
let d = new Date(2017,0,1);
console.log(d);
```

The Chrome result is what i expect regarding to the documentation:

```
Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

The NodeJS result is other than expected based on monthIndex from 0 to 11

```
2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

Aditional the format seems different. So where is the official documentation for NodeJS as the MDN documentation doesn't seem to apply for NodeJS

EDIT:
The ECMA documentation (which is the official versiona also states the range to be 0 - 11 and not 1-12)

> Months are identified by an integer in the range 0 to 11, inclusive.

EDIT 2:
The implementation seems different for node and Chrome(any Browser) due time zones. So browsers in time zone GMT +1 are one hour ahead of node (at least from the dd.MM.yyyy representation)

But why isn't node returning 1.1.2017 00:00 and browsers 1.1.2017 01:00 GTM +0100
?

### ----------------------[Solution]-------------------------

When you use `new Date([Whatever])` it allways create the date in your time zone.
But depending of the implementation it shows in GMT +0000 or in your own timezone.
So if you like to create an date and you don't care about the timezone which will mostly be the case on NodeJS you should use Date.UTC to create The date in GTM +0000

Comment: No, the official specification for JS is at https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm MDN, while a reliable source of documentation, is not exactly "official" (it's basically a wiki)

Comment: But why has Chrome(opera) an different output than Node

Comment: If you look closely, you see that *both dates are the same*. They are just shown differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS is an ECMAScript engine, and thus it *does follow the specification*. Both object constructors work exactly the same way.

At midnight here in central europe, when we already celebrated new years eve, the people living in the greenwhich timezone still had to wait one hour. So both dates actually represent the same *point in time*, just in different local times.

But why does NodeJS show the date in Zulu time while the browser shows it in the local timezone?

Well thats because you pass the date object to the *console*, and the console *is not specified*. It makes sense though that Chrome shows you the date in the local timezone, cause the browser is meant to show data to the user, and the user is only interested in his local time, wereas NodeJS is built for servers, and they run independently of their location (does it matter wether your server is running in frankfurt, new york or tokyo? No, not really).

Comment: So `new Date(2017,0,1);` should return 2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z

Comment: Shouldn't return Chrome Sun Jan 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 and Node Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00

Comment: Yes. the console represents it in a way thats useful for debugging. No one really uses zero based months right?

Comment: `new Date` is for *local time*, so you get midnight here in western europe. To construct a zulu date use `Date.UTC`